# Trouble with populating an empty list of lists using a nested for loop in R

Tags: r

I am trying to make a list of 288 lists each with 3 values, extracted from a different list of data frames. I am trying to make each list have all the corresponding nth row values for every 6th data frame from the list of data frames (called OtherList which has 36 dataframes and each dataframe has 288 rows).

I tried to make an empty list of 288 lists first, then used a nested for loop. But I’m stuck on why it is saying “Error: unexpected '}' in “}”” for my nested for loop. Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

```
Empty = c(1:288)
MyList <- list()
for (a in Empty){
  MyList[[a]] <- list()
}

for (Z in 1:288){ 
  for (M in seq(1, 36, 12)) { 
    MyList[Z] <- OtherList[[M]][[“X”]][Z,1]
  }
}
```

EDIT* Sorry, I should have specified OtherList:

The OtherLIst basically is a list of 36 data frames that each have two columns and 288 rows.

```
Here is (str(OtherList)) 

List of 36
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ X           :'data.frame':    288 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ CO2   : num [1:288] 5 2 0 990 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 ..
  .. ..$ O2      : num [1:288] 9 14 26 276 274 264 258 252 250 250 ..
```

EDIT #2 * I had 4 in my [Z,4] in my for loop originally but changed it to 1

Comment: It looks like you may have curly (smart) quotes around `X` in your `for` loop. Try replacing with plain quotes (`"X"`).

Comment: Oh, that got rid of the error but it says object 'X' is not found. Would there be another way to refer to my OtherList (the other list of dataframes) instead of "X"? I used the "X" because it's how the console named it as OtherList[[1]][["X"]]

Comment: What is `OtherList` please show a small reproducible example

Comment: @Medward - can you share the structure of `OtherList`? (`str(OtherList)`)

Comment: Looks like there are two column s in `"X"` and you. are using `4` for column index

Comment: Just edited in str(OtherList). I've been having trouble with pasting a table that represents what it looks like but it would have 2 columns and 288 rows.

Comment: @akrun Oh I see, I just changed it back to 1 for the column index but it still says Error in X : object 'X' not found. Sorry for my code messiness.

Comment: The issue is with. indexing it.  you have a nested list.  `OtherList[[M]]` gets inside the first list.  then there is another `List of 2` before you get into `X` i.e. `OtherList[[M]][[1]][['X']][Z, 1]` would get the values from the 1st list

Comment: Oh, I see. So the order is different between M and Z. I'll try working on it with that in mind. Thank you for your time and help Akrun and Ben! I appreciate it!

Comment: You may need another loop inside i.e. `for (M in seq(1, 36, 12)) { for(i in 1:2){OtherList[[M]][[i]][['X']][Z, 1]`

Comment: That makes sense to me but it kept saying subscript out of bounds, but it does seem to work now after I redefined the empty list for some reason! Thank you!